# glassfish cannot start bundle org.glassfish.main.admingui.glassfish-osgi-console-plugin

Tags: osgi, glassfish-3, apache-felix

I want to use glassfish 3.1.2.2 with OSGI for my development purposes. I installed OSGI Future pack over web administration console and restarted glassfish. After server restarting the web console stopped to work and shows me only a blank page without any errors. I looked in a log file and found there exception described bellow.

I had a number of questions:

1. How to replace start level of this bundle and which level it is necessary to set?
2. How to get access to Apache Felix's shell?
3. Whether it is possible to marry glassfish and karaf?

```
[org.glassfish.main.admingui.glassfish-osgi-console-plugin(Glassfish OSGI Console Plugin):3.1.2.1-SNAPSHOT]
    com.sun.enterprise.module.ResolveError: Failed to start Bundle Id [263]  State [RESOLVED]        [org.glassfish.main.admingui.glassfish-osgi-console-plugin(Glassfish OSGI Console Plugin):3.1.2.1-SNAPSHOT]
            at org.jvnet.hk2.osgiadapter.OSGiModuleImpl.start(OSGiModuleImpl.java:177)
            at org.jvnet.hk2.osgiadapter.OSGiModuleImpl$2$1$1.loadClass(OSGiModuleImpl.java:344)
            at com.sun.hk2.component.LazyInhabitant.loadClass(LazyInhabitant.java:124)
            at com.sun.hk2.component.LazyInhabitant.fetch(LazyInhabitant.java:111)
            at com.sun.hk2.component.EventPublishingInhabitant.get(EventPublishingInhabitant.java:135)
            at com.sun.hk2.component.AbstractInhabitantImpl.get(AbstractInhabitantImpl.java:78)
            at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ClassLoaderHierarchyImpl.createApplicationParentCL(ClassLoaderHierarchyImpl.java:200)
            at org.glassfish.deployment.common.DeploymentContextImpl.createClassLoader(DeploymentContextImpl.java:216)
            at org.glassfish.deployment.common.DeploymentContextImpl.createDeploymentClassLoader(DeploymentContextImpl.java:199)
            at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:346)
            at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLoaderService.processApplication(ApplicationLoaderService.java:375)
            at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.adapter.InstallerThread.load(InstallerThread.java:210)
            at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.adapter.InstallerThread.run(InstallerThread.java:108)
    Caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Cannot start bundle org.glassfish.main.admingui.glassfish-osgi-console-plugin [263] because its start level is 2, which is greater than the framework's start level of 1.
            at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:1807)
            at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:944)
            at org.jvnet.hk2.osgiadapter.OSGiModuleImpl.start(OSGiModuleImpl.java:169)
            ... 12 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a well known issue [1] and it has been fixed in GlassFish trunk. A work around is available for 3.1.x release as well.

[1] http://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-18880